# Basic obstruction to anything like holomophic symmetric functions of infinitely many variables?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

The totality of all holomorphic functions on the unit disk forms some sort of infinite-dimensional complex manifold, where the coefficients of the Taylor expansion might serve as coordinates for the space.

Passing from the functions to their zero-sets fibers this set over the space of infinite discrete subsets of the disk, also some sort of infinite-dimensional complex manifold.

I'd like to know if there's a general obstruction to the existence of any kind of holomorphic cross-section.  Perhaps even there are no non-constant holomorphic functions on the base space at all?

I understand that there's no naive generalization available from the usual elementary symmetric polynomials to infinitely many variables.  Indeed the delicate nature of the Weierstrass factorization theorem reflects that.  So I suppose I'm looking for a general principle that would imply that any Weierstrass-like theorem must involve, in an essential way, putting something like an order on the zero set, so that the output can't vary nicely across all zero-sets.

Comment: What topology on the discrete subsets of $D$ do you have in mind here?

Comment: I was trying not to be too specific in case someone knew a relevant theorem.   But I'd be happy with the Hausdorff metric.  I'd be happy with considering first sequences, considering them in the product (topology) of countably many disks, then taking a quotient by the action of the full symmetric group.

Comment: I don't see why the Weierstrass factorization theorem can't apply in a canonical way. You can just choose an ordering on the zero set in order of nondecreasing modulus, and choose your elementary factors $E_{p_n}$ with $p_n = n$. See Conway, Functions of One Complex Variable, theorems VII.5.12 and VII.5.15. For whatever natural complex structure you choose on the spaces involved I expect this section would be analytic.

Comment: If you have a tie between the modulus of two zeros, then a perturbation could flip how they stand in the order, causing a discontinuity in the choice of elementary factors, right?

Comment: In general a path in ordered-zero-set space space that induces a permutation on the zeros, so a loop in unordered-zero-set space will drag along an discrete invariants attached to the zeros.